# Graphing 3 function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I wish to graph this[image]

This graph has 3 functions on it

t=x-r, r<0, x<0
x=r, r>1, x>1
(x-r)/(1-r), 0

My problem is I am wishing to stop the (x-r)/(1-r) lines at the point (1,1) as seen in my drawing below. Could anyone help me with this please?

Currently have this, also struggling with drawing the vertical lines.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-1, xmax=1.5,
            ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
            axis lines=center,
            axis on top=true,
            domain=-2:3,
        ]
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+1};
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+2};
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+1.5};
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x};
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+0.5};
            \addplot [mark=none,draw=green,ultra thick] {(x-.5)/(1-.5)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `domain` as an option to `addplot`. The vertical lines you can simply draw using the `draw` macro. By adding the `axis cs` prefix to a coordinate you can use the axis coordinate system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-1, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=true,
    ]
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+1};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+2};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+1.5};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+0.5};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=green,ultra thick, domain={0:1}] {(x-.5)/(1-.5)};
    \draw[draw=blue, ultra thick] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,1.5);
    \draw[draw=blue, ultra thick] (axis cs:1.5,0) -- (axis cs:1.5,1.5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: pgfplots]

Comment: If you use a version of PGFplots `>=1.11`, then `axis cs` is not needed and automatically used.  You have to make sure to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` in the preamble (1.13 is the current PGFplots version).

Comment: @JP-Ellis Very convenient. I did not know that. Thanks for making me aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another solution (wow, they came fast!)

In order to avoid repeating yourself, I've used `\foreach` to loop over values; however, it requires a little trick in certain circumstances due to the way things are expanded and parsed.  Essentially, a temporary macro, `\tmp`, is created so that it contains (in the case of the first iteration):

```
\tmp = \addplot [green] (0.25, 0) -- (1, 1);
```

In order to get `\i` to become `0.25` but `\addplot` to remain as is, `\edef` is used which expands all macros it encounters within the definition.  In order to prevent `\addplot` for being expanded though, `\noexpand` is added in front and `\tmp` becomes defined as above.

I also made the red lines stop at `x=1`, but you can easily change that by removing `domain=-1:1`.

Lastly, I use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}` in order to get the value of `ymax` so that the vertical lines are guaranteed to go to the top of the plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
      xmin=-1,
      xmax=1.5,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1.5,
      axis lines=center,
      axis on top=true,
      domain=-2:3,
    ]

    \foreach \i in {0, 0.25, ..., 2} {
      \addplot [red, domain=-1:1] {x + \i};
    }
    \foreach \i in {0.25, 0.50, 0.76} {
      \edef\tmp{
        \noexpand\draw [green] (\i, 0) -- (1, 1);
      }
      \tmp
    }
    \foreach \i in {1.00, 1.25, 1.50} {
      \edef\tmp{
        \noexpand\draw [blue] (\i, 0) -- (\i, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
      }
      \tmp
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

The domain for this specific line(s) can be set separately by adding, e.g., `domain=.5:1` like this:

```
\documentclass [10pt] {article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-1, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top=true,
    domain=-2:3,
    ]
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+1};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+2};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+1.5};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=red,ultra thick] {x+0.5};
    \addplot [mark=none,draw=green,ultra thick,domain=.5:1] {(x-.5)/(1-.5)};
    \draw[draw=blue, ultra thick] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,1.5);
    \draw[draw=blue, ultra thick] (axis cs:1.5,0) -- (axis cs:1.5,1.5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]