# Drawing a simple graph with shortened functions

Tags: diagrams

I wish to draw the following graph:

[image: wanted]

which has 3 functions. (Then I just add different constants to get more lines.)

x-r=t, r<0, x<0
x=r, r>0, x>1
(x-r)/(1-r)=t, 0

with the (x-r)/(1-r)=t 'stopping' at the point (1,1).

I can get it all apart from the 'stop'.

Comment: And what about the [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296369/graphing-3-function/296371#296371)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->](-4,0)--(6,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->](0,-2)--(0,8)node[left]{$t$};

\foreach \i  in {3,4,5}
{
\draw[xshift=\i cm](0,0)--(0,7);
    }
    \foreach \i  in {0,1,2,3}
{
\draw(\i,0)--(3,3);
    }
\foreach \i  in {-3,-2,-1,0}
{
\draw[xshift=\i cm](0,0)--(45:7);
    }
    \node[below] at (3,0) {$1$};
        \node[left] at (0,3) {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]